# How can i write crontab script for .sh file of copying the file from AWS s3 folder to my local ec2 folder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I want to write the crontab script for copy the file from AWS s3 folder to my local aws ec2 . I can just run the command at my linux command by

`aws s3 cp s3://sftp-test/test.txt /u02/app/oracle/test/`

So the test.txt file will be copy from s3 to my local u02 folder. But when i write at my command line at .sh file and then it does not work. First i create test.sh file by

```
#!/bin/sh
*/5 * * * * aws s3 cp s3://sftp-customs/test.txt /u02/app/oracle/test/
```

Second i call that crontab by

`crontab test.sh`

Then i can see the my script when i used

`crontab -l`

But overall it does not work. I don't received any file from server. Thanks for your time all. Please help with some advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell file must be like:

```
#!/bin/sh
source ~/.bash_profile #or .bashrc
aws s3 cp s3://sftp-customs/test.txt /u02/app/oracle/test/
```

and in cron (using `crontab -e) you should enter

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/test.sh
```

alternatively create new file (`test.txt` for example) with content:

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/test.sh
```

and execute command:

```
crontab test.txt
```

NB! The last command will replace your entire cron